# How I should write Jersey rest service to make is accessible by given spring code

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

Here is rest client that is written using Spring:

```
public void addGadget(String gadgetName, String gadgetUrl) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("gadgetName", gadgetName);
    map.put("gadgetUrl", gadgetUrl);
    restTemplate.postForLocation(restServiceUrl, map);
}
```

This is not my code and I cannot change it. I should write rest service, but without spring, using jersey. Here is my code but it doesn't work:

```
@Path("gadgets")
public class RestService {

@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response addGadget(@FormParam("gadgetUrl") String gadgetUrl,
        @FormParam("gadgetName") String gadgetName) throws Exception {
    //some logic
    return Response.status(201).build();
}
}
```

When I try to access this service using spring client, I get exception:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415
>   Unsupported Media Type

How should I re-write my service declaration (I guess the problem is with Consumes annotation) in order to make it accessible for spring client with unchanged spring code.

Answer (score 0):

When you type:

```
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

You are narrowing the type acceptable by your service. Please try not to do this and just erase this line of code and see what happens. If it will not help it means that RestTemplate is set up to use some unknown media type. If so please check what is the media type sent by Spring RestTemplate object. If removing @Consumes will not help write what is the media type  sent from RestTemplate so that I could help more.